# width: 100% doesn't work inside td table cell

Tags: html, css

The label doesn't get its width the same as the `td` it is inside of.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

table label {
  width: 100%;
}

table td:not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><label>hey</label></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I make the label the same width as its parent td?

Comment: label is an inline element. use inline-block

Comment: As you make everything with border label is fit 100% but border is bordered it so in table unset border for label
`table label {
  width: 100%;
  border: unset;
}`

Comment: `display: inline-block;` fixes it